# change column name

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm needing to update a few column names in some tables I have in my database.  I'm using `SQL Server 2012`.

I'm aware of using the `RENAME` ability:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
   RENAME COLUMN old_name to new_name;
```

or by using the `SQL Server Management Studio` by pulling up the Table's Design and then just updating the name for the column and saving the changes.

What I need to know is if either of these drops the column in question.  I don't want to lose any of the data, I just want to rename the column name to something else.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE .... RENAME COLUMN` is not valid T-SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend SQL Server Management Studio's Table Designer, since in my experience, it will create a new table, move all the data, then drop the old table and rename the new table.

The syntax for renaming a column is not to `ALTER TABLE`, but to use `sp_rename`:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'table_name.old', 'new_name', 'COLUMN';
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188617(v=sql.110).aspx

The `sp_rename` stored procedure only changes the name and does not manipulate the data.

EDIT: Code corrected per shadonar.

Comment: just a quick update on this, the `sp_rename` for changing column names is:   

    `EXEC sp_rename 'table_name.old_name', 'new_name', 'COLUMN';`